# How to enable next/prev with prettyPhoto when links are within <li>

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I have a gallery with the following markup:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <figure>
        <a href="myimg1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="thumb1.jpg" /></a>
        <figcaption>
        some stuff here
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</li>
<li>
    <figure>
        <a href="myimg2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="thumb2.jpg" /></a>
        <figcaption>
        some stuff here
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</li>
</ul>
```

As far as I can tell, for the automated next/previous navigation to work, the image links need  to be beside each other in the DOM. Is there any easy way to get it to work with the above structure? I looked over the options but couldn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All I did to get this working was to modify the `rel` attribute of the images, so this:

```
<a href="myimg1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="thumb1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="myimg2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"><img src="thumb2.jpg" /></a>
```

Becomes this:

```
<a href="myimg1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_name]"><img src="thumb1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="myimg2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery_name]"><img src="thumb2.jpg" /></a>
```

Doing so got me the next/previous controls. I found the details for this on the prettyPhoto [home page](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#image-gallery-overview).

My Javascript was this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        theme: 'facebook',
        slideshow: 5000,
        autoplay_slideshow: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how i missed it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation) you can simply use the public API.

```
jQuery.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
jQuery.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');
```

For example try adding something like this to your markup:

```
<div id="prettyphoto-controls">
  <span onclick="jQuery.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');">&lt; Previous</span> |
  <span onclick="jQuery.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');">Next &gt;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Given the problem posed in the question, the `changePage` method probably won't do anything as `prettyPhoto` only appears to be picking up the first image if we use the given HTML.

Comment: Hm after reading the question again I see what you mean. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue of no navigation on prettyPhoto by simply adding [ppgal] within the quotation marks

Like this:

```
rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"
```